# Sort output from ls command

Tags: sorting, ls

I'm trying to sort the output from ls. The order that I'm going for is this:

- any directories with names that begin with _
- any directories with names that begin with +
- all soft links (which may include some dot files)
- all remaining .files
- all remaining .directories
- everything else

Everything is sorted alphabetically within these 'sublists'. At the moment I'm using the find command a number of times to find files meeting the criteria above. Following that I pipe the output from find to sort and then pass the entire sorted list to ls:

```
#!/bin/bash

find1=`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "_*" -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort`
find2=`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "+*" -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort`
find3=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\n" | sort`
find4=`find . -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort`
find5=`find . -maxdepth 1 \( ! -name "."  \) -name ".*" -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort`
find6=`find . -maxdepth 1 \( ! -name "_*" \) \( ! -name "+*" \) \( ! -name ".*" \) \( ! -type l \) -printf "%f\n"`
find="$find1 $find2 $find3 $find4 $find5 $find6"
ls -dfhlF --color=auto $find
```

This doesn't handle any names that contain spaces, and overall seems a bit excessive. I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd suggest `ls` or `ls -l` and then grepping for the files you want (or don't want) each time.  Remember, `grep -v` will print files that _don't_ match a pattern.  You can use the output of `ls -l` to find directories and links.

Comment: It's a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`. In the worst case, there will be filenames that contain newlines, in which case you cannot distinguish between those newlines and the ones that `ls` inserts for formatting.

Comment: @AdamLiss Could you elaborate on that a bit more? Do you mean to just grep the results of ls and search for a specific pattern when I want to list only those files? I was hoping to have a robust solution for listing the contents in a directory in a certain order. i.e. enter ll (name of script in $HOME/bin) and have the contents of the directory shown in long listing format (ls -al sort of thing) but with the list organised in a specific way. Makes the list more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?  It prints the files in the order you specified, but it won't print them in color.  In order to do that, you'd need to strip the ANSI codes from the names before pattern-matching them.  As it is, it will handle filenames with embedded spaces, but not horribly pathological names, like those with embedded newlines or control characters.

I think the `awk` script is fairly self-explanatory, but let me know if you'd like clarification.  The `BEGIN` line is processed before the `ls` output starts, and the `END` line is processed after all the output is consumed.  The other lines start with an optional condition, followed by a sequence of commands enclosed in curly brackets.  The commands are executed on (only) those lines that match the condition.

```
ls -ahlF --color=none | awk '
  BEGIN { name_col = 45 }
  { name = substr($0, name_col) }
  name == "" { next }
  /^d/ && substr(name, 1, 1) == "_" { under_dirs = under_dirs $0 "\n"; next }
  /^d/ && substr(name, 1, 1) == "+" { plus_dirs = plus_dirs $0 "\n"; next }
  /^l/ { links = links $0 "\n"; next }
  /^[^d]/ && substr(name, 1, 1) == "." { dot_files = dot_files $0 "\n"; next }
  /^d/ && substr(name, 1, 1) == "." { dot_dirs = dot_dirs $0 "\n"; next }
  { others = others $0 "\n" }
  END { print under_dirs plus_dirs links dot_files dot_dirs others }
'
```